# VBA: Hide rows where cell value matches target row cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet like so:

```
A        B          C          D          E           F        G
12       Row1                                                  Click to Hide
12       Row2                                                  Click to Hide
5        Row3                                                  Click to Hide
4        Row4                                                  Click to Hide
12       Row5                                                  Click to Hide
```

When the user clicks 'Click to Hide' I am trying to hide all rows which have a matching number from that target row in column A.

So for instance if the user clicks 'Click to Hide' in column G on row1. Where the number is 12, then Row1, Row2 and Row5 would get hidden - because these all have the same number.

However, to complicate the matter, i do not want to hide the target row. Which means Row1 wouldn't be hidden, and instead only Row2 and Row 5 would be hidden.

Here's my code:

```
'Hide ROws


 If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "Click to Hide" Then
        valu = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
        For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If Cells(i, 1).Value = valu Then
                Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next i
        Target.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows.Hidden = False
    End If
```

The code doesn't seem to be working, it hides other rows at the top of my spreadsheet which are empty and do not have a matching number. I'm not sure why this is, please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why didn't you ask for guidance from the person who gave you that code in your [Last Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883884/excel-vba-hide-all-rows-where-value-active-cell-offset-cell-value)

Comment: Also this is your fourth question.  The other three all have answer, to which the only feedback given was that the one did not work.  If the answers worked then you should mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Without feedback there are those that will stop helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub HideRows()
    BeginRow = 1
    EndRow = 100
    ChkCol = 1

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 12 Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read the question again. Your code would hide all rows with 12. Including the one he clicked at. Also it would hide the 12's if a row is clicked which is not 12 ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel, I am not doing his work for him. I am posting code for him to reference as he has posted the same question 3 times.

Comment: *I am not doing his work for him.* is not a valid answer. There is an error in his code and because we are bad ppl, we are not going to tell him where. But giving an **answer** which simply does not solve the problem at all, may be voted down.

Comment: @DirkReichel then supply him a complete answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with giving him another scope or reference for him to adjust his code.

Comment: If you add some explanation - it would be nice :)